# Sublime Text 3 Build Many Source Files

Tags: c++, build, qmake, sublimetext3

Well all I've seen for build systems for C++ is the following:

```
"build_systems":
    [
        {
           "name: "g++ test",
            "cmd": ["g++", "${file}"],
            "shell": true
        }
        {
                    "name": "echo test",
            "cmd": ["echo", "${file}"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
```

Just as a test, this only works for the currently opened file, which might not even be a source file nor part of the sublime project. So this is good for a test program that only has one source but it isn't that useful otherwise.

Question 1:
Is there any `${project_files}` variable with regex to accept only .cpp files ?

Question 2:
I would want to pass these files to qmake, such that it generates a .pro project file. Such that if I add a file to a sublime project it and build the file will be added to the project file. How would I do this without shell script or otherwise such that it's cross platform ?

Comment: I would do this the other way round, add files to my qmake project file and then have sublime text call qmake to compile the project.

Comment: The issue is I only want to add it to one place, editing the qmake project file every time I want to add a file is just so un-intuitive.